# How to show UIView like UIAction sheet using UIView animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiview, uiactionsheet

Hi I am very new for iOS and I have added a `UIView` at bottom of `MainViewController`.

And when I tap on a button that `UIView` displays like "**UIAction sheet**" using `UIView` animations.

And for this I have tried the code below but animations are not applying when I tap on the button.

Please help me.

### my code:-

```
#import "AnimationUIview.h"

@interface AnimationUIview ()
{
    UIView * firstView;
    NSLayoutConstraint * Bottom;
}

@end

@implementation AnimationUIview

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstView);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[firstView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[firstView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    Bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                          toItem:self.view
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                      multiplier:1
                                        constant:80];
    [self.view addConstraint:Bottom];
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         Bottom.constant = -10;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "AnimationUIview.h"

@interface AnimationUIview () {
    UIView * firstView;
    NSLayoutConstraint * Bottom;
    BOOL isshown;
}

@end
@implementation AnimationUIview
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstView);

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[firstView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[firstView(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    Bottom = [
             NSLayoutConstraint
             constraintWithItem:firstView
             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
             toItem:self.view
             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
             multiplier:1
             constant:80
    ];
    [self.view addConstraint:Bottom];
    isshown=No;

}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    if (isshown==NO) {
        firstview.frame =  CGRectMake(0,0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.40 animations:^{
            firstview.frame =  CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-100, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100);
            [firstview setAlpha:0.0f];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];

        isshow=Yes;
    } else {
        firstview.frame =  CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-100, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.40 animations:^{
            firstview.frame =  CGRectMake(0,0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100);
            firstview.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [firstview setHidden:YES];
    }];

    isshown=No;
}
@end
```